# Class to collect data from user

Tags: python

I am learning python from scratch and am stuck with classes what I am trying to achieve as follows:

> Problem statement: "Collect the data of different students into an array and display."

I am trying to achieve this using classes.
Below is my code which I am trying out. Need help on how to get the values of different question into one single dimensional array.

i.e.
`["brittos school", "Ahmedabad", "Francis", "34", " 36", "anthony's school", "Mumbai", "Sam", "45", " 55"]`

Where 34 36 are the marks of the subject.

```
class Mack:
    def getmarks(self,numberofsubjects,numberofstudents,sub):
        marks=[]
        for i in range(numberofstudents):
            self.sname=input("Enter your School Name: ")
            a.append(marks)
            self.city=input("Enter the School City: ")
            a.append(marks)
            self.name=input("Enter your Name")
            a.append(marks)
            a=[]
            for j in range(numberofsubjects):
                a.append(int(input(f"Enter the Marks for {sub[j]} ")))
            marks.append(a)

    def show(self):
        print("My Name is: ",self.name)
        print("My City is: ",self.city)

sub=[]
numberofstudents=int(input("Input the number of students"))
numberofsubjects=int(input("Input the number of subjects"))

for i in range(0, numberofsubjects):
        ele = input(f"enter the subject name :{i+1}")
        sub.append(ele)

ab=Mack()
for i in range(0,numberofstudents):
    ab.getmarks(numberofstudents,numberofsubjects,sub)
```

Comment: Your indentation is clearly wrong; please [edit] to fix it. On the desktop version of this site, you can get code marked up for you by pasting your code, selecting the pasted block, and typing ctrl-K.

Comment: You should probably define a `Student` class and create a **`list`** of them. Generally avoid putting the user interface, like using `input()` out of the class so it's independent of it. To create the list of `Student` instance, write a loop the gets the information from the user and uses it to create a class instance, then append that instance to the list being created.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are using the same loop outside the getmarks function and inside it so for example if I input number of students as 2. It will run 4 times which is incorrect. Loop over number of students once. Secondly a is not defined anywhere so if you want the list of all the input I'd suggest creating a as a member variable of this class.
I think this code below is what you need

```
class Mack:
    def getmarks(self,numberofsubjects,numberofstudents,sub):
        marks=[]
        a = []
        for i in range(numberofstudents):
            self.sname=input("Enter your School Name: ")
            a.append(self.sname)
            self.city=input("Enter the School City: ")
            a.append(self.city)
            self.name=input("Enter your Name")
            a.append(self.name)
            for j in range(numberofsubjects):
                a.append(int(input(f"Enter the Marks for {sub[j]} ")))
            marks.append(a)
        
        return a

    def show(self):
        print("My Name is: ",self.name)
        print("My City is: ",self.city)

sub=[]
numberofstudents=int(input("Input the number of students"))
numberofsubjects=int(input("Input the number of subjects"))

for i in range(0, numberofsubjects):
    ele = input(f"enter the subject name :{i+1}")
    sub.append(ele)

ab=Mack()

result = ab.getmarks(numberofstudents,numberofsubjects,sub)
print(result)
```

Although this is a very bad approach to do what you are trying to do. What I would suggest is to create a Student Class like.

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self, name, sname, cname, subjects, marks):
        self.name = name
        self.sname = sname
        self.cname = cname
        self.subjects = subjects
        self.marks = marks
```

where subjects and marks would lists of subjects and marks. You can also create a dictionary if you want where subject would be key and marks would be value. After that, you can simple create a list of this class and take input for every element of that Student list.